# How to pinch with two fingers in iOS app automation with swift

Tags: ios11, xcode9, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, swift3.2

I want to apply pinch-in and pinch-out gesture into a imageView in my application.

I am using Xcode9 and swift 3.2

I could not able to tap on specific two coordinate at a time of my desired image

```
app.scrollViews.scrollViews.images.element(boundBy: 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For zoom in or zoom out you have to use `pinch(withScale:velocity:)` method of xctest.

Your code should look like below

```
let image = app.scrollViews.scrollViews.images.element(boundBy: 0)
```

**Zoom in:**

```
image.pinch(withScale: 3, velocity: 1) // zoom in
```

**Zoom out:**

```
image.pinch(withScale: 0.5, velocity: -1) // zoom out
```

According to api [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1618669-pinch) of `pinch(withScale:velocity:)` negative velocity is for `zoom out` and positive velocity is for `zoom in`

Please use the above code and let me know your feedback.

Comment: Hey, is there any way to verify whether image got really Zoomed or not in xcuitest ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pinch(withScale:velocity:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1618669-pinch) on your image element.

```
let image = app.scrollViews.scrollViews.images.element(boundBy: 0)
image.pinch(withScale: 3, velocity: 1) // zoom in
image.pinch(withScale: 0.5, velocity: -1) // zoom out
```

Comment: Thanks @Oletha, for your feedback. I have tried with your code, zoom in working perfectly but zoom out not worked well. I have tried with different values and ways also but it is not working for me. Would u plz provide how this working for U.

Comment: I'm not actually using this API in my project, I'm just going off the documentation linked above. After zooming in a lot, the scale for zooming back out potentially needs to be very small.

Comment: According to your provided value, zoom out not working

Comment: Did you try with a negative value?

Comment: scale can not be negative according to api documentation.

Comment: Ok, try the same scale with the inverse velocity. Thanks @MahmudRiad for pointing out the velocity can be negative. That makes sense since velocity has direction as well as speed.

Comment: Apple Docs say "The scale of the pinch gesture. Use a scale between 0 and 1 to "pinch close" or zoom out"